# How to catch this specific exception in Python - amazon.api

Tags: python, api, amazon-web-services

API I am using: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-amazon-simple-product-api

I have this part of my code

```
from amazon.api import AmazonAPI
products = self.amazon_api.search_n(1, Keywords=item['upc'], SearchIndex='All')
```

Exception I got

```
SearchException: Amazon Search Error: 'AWS.ECommerceService.NoExactMatches', 'We did not find any matches for your request.'
```

I tried catching it like this

```
try:
    products = self.amazon_api.search_n(1, Keywords=item['upc'], SearchIndex='All')
    found_match = True
except SearchException:
    logging.warning("No search result found on Amazon for UPC: %s"%(item['upc']))
    found_match = False
```

But I got

```
NameError: global name 'SearchException' is not defined
```

Then I did this in start of my script

```
from AWS.ECommerceService.NoExactMatches import SearchException
```

But then I got this error

```
ImportError: No module named AWS.ECommerceService.NoExactMatches
```

My question is how do I silently catch this specific `SearchException` exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
from amazon.api import AmazonAPI, SearchException
```

After that,

```
try:
    products = self.amazon_api.search_n(1, Keywords=item['upc'], SearchIndex='All')
    found_match = True
except SearchException:
    logging.warning("No search result found on Amazon for UPC: %s"%(item['upc']))
    found_match = False
```

should work as expected.

Docs can be found [here](http://pythonhosted.org/python-amazon-simple-product-api/amazon.html#amazon.api.SearchException).

Answer (score -1):

Try the `NoExactMatches` exception:

```
from AWS.EcommerceServiec import NoExactMatches

try:
    products = self.amazon_api.search_n(1, Keywords=item['upc'], 
SearchIndex='All')
    found_match = True
except NoExactMatches:
    logging.warning("No search result found on Amazon for UPC: %s"%(item['upc']))
    found_match = False
```

Comment: Also, modern IDEs (at least PyCharm — definitely) allow you to import anything by just typing the name of class/method/exception/constant etc. and press Alt + Enter. It saves a lot of time.